# sed regex to extract selector from method declaration (Obj-C)

Tags: objective-c, macos, command-line, sed

I'm converting an Objective-C method declaration to its [selector](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Selector.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH48-SW1), i.e. removing the parameter names and types like for this `NSString` method:

`- (void)getCString:(char *)buffer maxLength:(NSUInteger)maxLength`

to get

`getCString:maxLength:`

So I've figured out that the regular expression `\w*?\:` will extract what I need (works fine in an online regex-checker like http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) but I just can't get `sed` (on OS X) to work with the regular expression to extract the signature.

From various sed snippet/sample pages I've got the impression that something like this should work, except it doesn't (nor the ~250 variations I've tried...):

```
 cat test.m | sed '/\w*?\:/p'
```

Can any `sed` wizard give a hand?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect it to do. Assuming your sed accepts a regular expression like that - "standard" sed is pretty limited in regex features - it will print the entire line. (To get even that far you need to tell sed not to print _every_ line: `sed -n '/\w*?\:/p'`)

Comment: Hmm, apparently it's way more versatile than that, e.g. allowing to  *"get Subject header, but remove initial "Subject: " portion"* as per [sed one liners](http://face.centosprime.com/macosxw/sed-one-liners/)

Comment: That's not even close to the same regex you posted. What you posted doesn't even display the line unless I turn on extended regular expressions (-r option). It definitely does not do any editing of the line (you need the s/// command for that)

Comment: Considering block return type with nested parentheses, it seems not possible to do this with only one regex even with the help of recursive patterns. Anyway, you can use this simple tool I made: http://erkanyildiz.me/lab/selectorextract/ - to compare your results from sed and check regex patterns I used, incase it can help you. It handles all kind of method declarations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to extract the method **selector**, not the method signature.  The method signature includes the return type and argument types.  The method selector includes only the keywords and colons.

You can tell sed to use POSIX extended regular expressions using the non-standard `-E` flag.

This might do what you want:

```
sed -E -n '/^[-+]/{
    s/^.[[:blank:]]*(\([^)]*\))?[[:blank:]]*//
    s/[[:blank:]]*[;{][[:blank:]]*$//
    s/:[^:]*([[:blank:]]|$)/:/g
    p
}' test.m
```

That's a rather complicated sed command for a beginner, so let's break it down.

1. The `-E` flag enables extended regular expressions on FreeBSD derivatives like Mac OS X.
2. The `-n` flag tells sed not to print every input line automatically.
3. `/^[-+]/` selects every line that starts with a `-` (for an instance method) or a `+` (for a class method).
4. `{` begins a group of sed commands, which will all be executed on each selected line.  The group ends at the matching `}`.
5. `s/^.[[:blank:]]*(\([^)]*\))?[[:blank:]]*//` removes the `-` or `+`, followed by any amount of whitespace, followed by the return type of the method, followed by any amount of whitespace.  It removes the return type by matching a `(` followed by any number of non-`)` characters followed by a `)`.  Note that the return type is actually optional; a method declared `- foo:(int)x;` is perfectly valid (and has a default return type of `id`).  Also note that this regular expression won't work properly if your method's return type is an explicit function pointer or block, like `- (void (^)(void))getBlock;`, because you cannot handle nested parentheses with a regular expression.
6. `s/[[:blank:]]*[;{][[:blank:]]*$//` removes the `;` or `{`, and any surrounding whitespace, from the end of the line.  This is important to make the next command work properly.
7. `s/:[^:]*([[:blank:]]|$)/:/g` matches a colon, followed by as many non-`:` characters as possible, followed by either whitespace or end-of-line, and replaces the match with just a colon.  The trailing `g` flag tells sed to do this for every match on the line.  This command removes argument types and names.  Note that this command will properly handle nested parentheses, unlike the command that removes the return type.  Also note that argument types are also optional; `- foo:bar` is a method that takes one argument (whose type defaults to `id`).

Example:

```
:; echo '- (void)getCString:(char *)buffer maxLength:(NSUInteger)maxLength' | sed -E -n '/^[-+]/{
    s/^.[[:blank:]]*(\([^)]*\))?[[:blank:]]*//
    s/[[:blank:]]*[;{][[:blank:]]*$//
    s/:[^:]*([[:blank:]]|$)/:/g
    p
}'
getCString:maxLength:
```

Note that this sed command will also work for methods that have no arguments, like `- (void)save;`.

Comment: Awesome, works like a breeze - and thanks for the brief 'intro to sed' :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
$ echo '- (void)getCString:(char *)buffer maxLength:(NSUInteger)maxLength ' |
perl -lne '/^\s*-\s*\(\w+\)\s*(\w+:)\([^\)]+\)\w+\s+(\w+:)/ && print $1, $2'
getCString:maxLength:
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sed version that works at least on the sample (it cheats a little, pulling maxLength from the end):

```
echo "- (void)getCString:(char *)buffer maxLength:(NSUInteger)maxLength" \
| sed -ne '/[[:alnum:]]:/{;s/^[^)]*)\s*\([^:]*:\).*)\([[:alnum:]]*\)$/\1\2:/;p}'
getCString:maxLength:
```

This one pulls maxLength: from the middle:

```
 echo "- (void)getCString:(char *)buffer maxLength:(NSUInteger)maxLength" \
| sed -ne '/[[:alnum:]]:/{;s/^[^)]*)\s*\([^:]*:\)[^)]*\s*\S*\s*\([^:]*:\).*/\1\2/;p}'
getCString:maxLength:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'[() ]' '{print $4 $8}' file
getCString:maxLength:

$ cat file
- (void)getCString:(char *)buffer maxLength:(NSUInteger)maxLength
```

Comment: Nice and concise.. alas, doesn't work with generic selectors containing more parameters like this one:  `- (void)drawInRect:(NSRect)dstRect fromRect:(NSRect)srcRect operation:(NSCompositingOperation)op fraction:(CGFloat)delta`

Comment: @Jay - it's important when posting a question to show some truly REPRESENTATIVE sample input so we don't waste time coming up with solutions for what you posted when that's not the input you really have to work on. If you update your question with some more realistic input and expected output I'll show you how to do it in awk.